# How do i fix the snapd.socket no such file or directory error on MxLinux?

Tags: store, haskell-snap-framework, snapcraft

I've been trying to install a couple of apps using `sudo snap install <nameofapp>`
But whenever I try this I always get the same error:

`error: cannot communicate with server: Post http://localhost/v2/snaps/standard-notes: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory`

**I'm on MXLINUX please help**

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am working with a Debian system (5.5.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.5.13-2kali1 (2020-04-03) x86_64 GNU/Linux)
).

I found that when I tried to install notepad++. I got the same error. These command worked for me. Hope they do for you.

```
sudo service snapd start
sudo systemctl start snapd.service
sudo snap install notepad-plus-plus
```

Comment: I tried `service snap start` and i got this error
`service snapd start snapd: unrecognized service`

Comment: What @KenKanaki said . and also i am inside ubuntu docker. maybe that is why

Comment: same issue i was getting on centos7 , started services of snapd and it worked , thanks for quick guide

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get install snapd 

service snapd start

sudo snap install notepad-plus-plus --edge
```

You will get updated Notepad++